# Why is `getdescriptorinfo` saying an xpub is not valid?

Tags: regtest, output-script-descriptors

I'm testing this with the examples provided [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md). More specifically this one:

```
wsh(sortedmulti(1,xpub661MyMwAqRbcFW31YEwpkMuc5THy2PSt5bDMsktWQcFF8syAmRUapSCGu8ED9W6oDMSgv6Zz8idoc4a6mr8BDzTJY47LJhkJ8UB7WEGuduB/1/0/*,xpub69H7F5d8KSRgmmdJg2KhpAK8SR3DjMwAdkxj3ZuxV27CprR9LgpeyGmXUbC6wb7ERfvrnKZjXoUmmDznezpbZb7ap6r1D3tgFxHmwMkQTPH/0/0/*))
```

From my raspberry pi running bitcoin core `v24.0.1`:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "wsh(sortedmulti(1,xpub661MyMwAqRbcFW31YEwpkMuc5THy2PSt5bDMsktWQcFF8syAmRUapSCGu8ED9W6oDMSgv6Zz8idoc4a6mr8BDzTJY47LJhkJ8UB7WEGuduB/1/0/*,xpub69H7F5d8KSRgmmdJg2KhpAK8SR3DjMwAdkxj3ZuxV27CprR9LgpeyGmXUbC6wb7ERfvrnKZjXoUmmDznezpbZb7ap6r1D3tgFxHmwMkQTPH/0/0/*))"
{
  "descriptor": "wsh(sortedmulti(1,xpub661MyMwAqRbcFW31YEwpkMuc5THy2PSt5bDMsktWQcFF8syAmRUapSCGu8ED9W6oDMSgv6Zz8idoc4a6mr8BDzTJY47LJhkJ8UB7WEGuduB/1/0/*,xpub69H7F5d8KSRgmmdJg2KhpAK8SR3DjMwAdkxj3ZuxV27CprR9LgpeyGmXUbC6wb7ERfvrnKZjXoUmmDznezpbZb7ap6r1D3tgFxHmwMkQTPH/0/0/*))#v66cvalc",
  "checksum": "v66cvalc",
  "isrange": true,
  "issolvable": true,
  "hasprivatekeys": false
}
```

From a docker image running bitcoin core `v23.0.0`:

```
$ docker exec -it bitcoin`enter code here`-dev bitcoin-cli -datadir=./.bitcoin getdescriptorinfo "wsh(sortedmulti(1,xpub661MyMwAqRbcFW31YEwpkMuc5THy2PSt5bDMsktWQcFF8syAmRUapSCGu8ED9W6oDMSgv6Zz8idoc4a6mr8BDzTJY47LJhkJ8UB7WEGuduB/1/0/*,xpub69H7F5d8KSRgmmdJg2KhpAK8SR3DjMwAdkxj3ZuxV27CprR9LgpeyGmXUbC6wb7ERfvrnKZjXoUmmDznezpbZb7ap6r1D3tgFxHmwMkQTPH/0/0/*))"
error code: -5
error message:
key 'xpub661MyMwAqRbcFW31YEwpkMuc5THy2PSt5bDMsktWQcFF8syAmRUapSCGu8ED9W6oDMSgv6Zz8idoc4a6mr8BDzTJY47LJhkJ8UB7WEGuduB' is not valid
```

Another difference is that the instance running in the docker container is in regtest mode while the other one is mainnet. But from [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90680/why-is-getdescriptorinfo-returning-an-error-invalid-descriptor-code-5#comment123290_90697) I take it that the descriptor format is independent from the network being used.

So what's the issue here? Descriptors are present since `0.17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But from here I take it that the descriptor format is independent from the network being used.

I believe you've misread the comment there.

The xpub and xprv formats **do** depend on the network, and by extension, so does the descriptor format.